# Viber в Debian x64

Tags: linux, debian

Не работает в Debian 8.3 x64: получается, банально не видит интернет подключение. Фаерволл открыт полностью, канал 50 мегабит... При запуске просит телефон но подключиться к сети не может...

Что странно, нашел в сети старую версию, работает без проблем, но нюанс в том, что не принимает кирилицу. Если ее выгрузить и запустить свежую версию вайбера - все прекрасно работает. До перезагрузки машины... Обращался в службу поддержки: они прислали инструкцию, как в убунте скачать вайбер и установить его... отладочного вывода у вайбера никакого нету... Спрашивается, как определять причину

Comment: А он запускается вообще? Если нет, проверь наличие пакета qt-default ( кажется так называется, давно ставил, не помню, оно в репах есть)

Answer (score 1):

**Устраняется так:**

Качаете эти сертификаты 
    https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem и
    https://github.com/katmagic/https-everywhere/blob/master/cert-validity/mozill...

Помещаете их в папку

`/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`

Запускаете в терминале

`sudo update-ca-certificates`